# JavaScript validation for Symfony 2 forms

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, symfony

Does exist Bundle which allows generate JavaScript equivalent to validators of Symfony 2 forms? I am looking for something similar to http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfJqueryFormValidationPlugin

If not, is it possible to do such thing for Symfony 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is new Symfony 2 bundle which provide better implementation of client side validation for forms https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle

Answer (score 3):

This bundle may suit your needs [APYJsFormValidationBundle](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYJsFormValidationBundle)

However it is currently limited to assert defined constraints, applied to entities.

Support for php, yml and xml defined constraints are on the todo list.